# How to run many linear regressions/correlations in one data set

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression, correlation

I have one data set in an excel/csv form. I wish to run many simple linear regressions/correlations (each with a p-value).

I have several independent variables (x's) and one dependent variable (y). 
The variables are all columns of data, not rows. Each column has the name of the data type in the first cell, and all the numerical data in the lower cells.

I want to create a loop instead of manually running each test, but I'm unfamiliar with loops in `R`. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.Thanks!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provide an example of your data set. it is possible to execute your proposed approach. I can try to answer your question using  a simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail it's hard to know for sure, but using dplyr and broom might get you where you need to go.

For example, this runs a linear model for each group:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do(tidy(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)))
```

For more detail, may I suggest: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to use a simulated data set to demonstrate 1) "manually" compute correlations, and 2) iteratively calculate correlation by a for loop in R:

First, generate data simulation with 2 independent variables `x1` (normally distributed) and `x2` (exponentially distributed), and a dependent variable `y` (same distribution as `x1`):

```
set.seed(1) #reproducibility
## The first column is your DEPENDENT variable
## The rest are independent variables
data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100,0.5,1), x1=rnorm(100,0,1), x2= rexp(100,0.5))
```

**"Manually" compute correlation:**

```
cor_x1_y <- cor.test(data$x1, data$y)
cor_x2_y <- cor.test(data$x2, data$y)

c(cor_x1_y$estimate, cor_x2_y$estimate) #corr. coefficients

##           cor           cor 
## -0.0009943199 -0.0404557828 

c(cor_x1_y$p.value, cor_x2_y$p.value) #p values
## [1] 0.9921663 0.6894252
```

**Iteratively compute correlation and store results in a matrix called** `results`:

```
results <- NULL # placeholder
for(i in 2:ncol(data)) {
  ## Perform i^th test:
  one_test <- cor.test(data[,i], data$y) 
  test_cor <- one_test$estimate
  p_value <- one_test$p.value
  ## Add any other parameters you'd like to include

  ##update results vector
  results <- rbind(results, c(test_cor , p_value))
}
colnames(results) <- c("correlation", "p_value")
results

##        correlation   p_value
## [1,] -0.0009943199 0.9921663
## [2,] -0.0404557828 0.6894252
```